# Suggestive search With Drop down in Java

Tags: java, autocomplete, dropdown

Dropdown suggestion works fine, but the problem is For example:

If I type for "Outlook" it shows(Dropdown) all the items which starts with "Outlook", but it doesn't show the items which contains "Outlook" in String.

I used `Autocompleter` Library here, also tried with `Autocomplete` Library Still same.

Is there another approach? or any changes need to be done?

Any Help is much appreciated.

## My Code:

```
//Below code when key Typed:
TextAutoCompleter complete=new TextAutoCompleter(t1);
complete.removeAllItems(); // Remove all from drowndown list
String temp = t1.getText(); //t1 is the textfield
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String value = null;
try{
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://src\\Mydb.accdb");
String sql = "select KB_Title from JD" ;
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs =pst.executeQuery();
while (rs.next())
{
    value = rs.getString(1);
    if(value.contains(temp))
        complete.addItem(rs.getString("KB_Title"));
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
}
```

Comment: Can you give more detail about those libraries ? I don't see what they do here since you access the DB yourself and do the check too.

Comment: Please use the below link for more details on Library:
https://serprogramador.es/autocompletar-java-swing-autocompleter/

Comment: That's in spanish... But reading this page would tell you "_mode - The mode is the way in which items are searched, there are 3 different modes, prefix (-1), infix (0), suffix (1). By default -1._" ... you have provided your own answer. Do you speak Spanish ? Because I don't ;)

Comment: @AxelH hahha, No i don't , I didn't get much about Library other than this page, i used page translate to read. :D

Comment: @AxelH changing Mode works fine thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
complete.setMode(0); // Infix mode, "contains"
```

And the SQL can be better:

```
// Not needed nowadays: Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
String sql = "select KB_Title from JD where KB_Title like ?";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://src\\Mydb.accdb");
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pst.setString(1, "%" + temp.trim() + "%");
    try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            value = rs.getString(1);
            complete.addItem(rs.getString("KB_Title"));
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe `order by length(KB_Title), KB_Title`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I made above changes, but its same
From my understanding its with Library which only displays the Suggestions based on first letter or word match it doesn't search in String, any other approach for this?

Comment: complete.setMode(0); this was the key.
Changing the mode works fine
Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a way around you can change your SQL statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '%Outlook%';
```

this statement will only return the values containing outlook